# How to obtain a specific property from GtkStyle?

Tags: c, gtk

I want to obtain the "base" property from a gtkstyle, which is a GdkColor type, but I just can manage to get it. I know I can use gtk_style_get_style_property()

```
void gtk_style_get_style_property  (GtkStyle *style,GType widget_type, const gchar *property_name, GValue *value);
```

but what am I supposed to put in "widget_type" and how a can get a gdkcolor type from "value"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass the [GType](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/unstable/gobject-Type-Information.html) of a widget class (e.g. `GTK_TYPE_LABEL`, `GTK_TYPE_BUTTON`, etc.) in `widget_type`.

To get a [GdkColor](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/stable/gdk-Colormaps-and-Colors.html) from a [GValue](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/unstable/gobject-Generic-values.html), call [g_value_get_boxed()](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/unstable/gobject-Standard-Parameter-and-Value-Types.html#g-value-get-boxed):

```
GdkColor *color = (GdkColor *) g_value_get_boxed(value);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. But now i see that i could have done style-<

Comment: No, accessing `widget->style` directly is deprecated and will be removed from GTK soon!